# ActionBar hides WebView. How to change size of WebView to avoid this hiding

Tags: blackberry, webview, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-cascades

I have a Web view in my app and ActionBar hides a bottom part of Webview. What schould I do to fit my WebView to the screen above Action Bar?

Here is my QML fragment:

```
         WebView {

                    id: webViewObj
                    visible: true
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                    settings.viewport: {
                        "width": "device-width",
                        "height": "device-height",
                        "initial-scale": 1.0
                    }

...

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather that do that use the [ActionBarAutoHideBehavior](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__actionbarautohidebehavior.html). This will allow you to use the action bar, but take advantage of all the screen to display the web data.

Comment: It would be a great idea, but I have already in my WebView scrolling functionality and I place my WebView in a not scrolling Container.  Because of this I cant use ActionBarAutoHideBehavior